How to stop Character from sliding (slopes) on terrains
when moving on terrain sometimes my character slides depending on the angle of the surface. How to stop this. if the terrain is plain the movement is perfect no issue but when the surface is a rounded player slides
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maximumSpeed;
    public float rotationSpeed;

    private Animator animator;
    private CharacterController characterController;
    private bool isRunning = false;
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movementDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0f, verticalInput);
        float inputMagnitude = Mathf.Clamp01(movementDirection.magnitude);
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Run"))
        {
            isRunning = !isRunning;
        }

        if (!isRunning)
        {
            inputMagnitude /= 1.5f;
        }
        animator.SetFloat("InputMagnitude", inputMagnitude, 0.05f, Time.deltaTime);
        float speed = inputMagnitude * maximumSpeed;
        movementDirection.Normalize();

        characterController.SimpleMove(movementDirection * maximumSpeed);

        if (movementDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", true);
            Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movementDirection, Vector3.up);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", false);
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
    {
        if (focus)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
    }
}

player settings
Sliding here per example
terrain
terrain](https://i.sstatic.net/KSD6k.jpg)
trying not to slide on these surfaces
Also added friction 10000000 still the same
friction
friction

friction dear boy, friction

^^ (Change the physics material to a custom one with lots of friction)

never mind, first time using the character controller from unity so added friction in code like this. the movement speed is being reduced but is still fine
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maximumSpeed;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float frictionFactor = 0.9f;

    private Animator animator;
    private CharacterController characterController;
    private bool isRunning = false;
    private Vector3 currentVelocity;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movementDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0f, verticalInput);
        float inputMagnitude = Mathf.Clamp01(movementDirection.magnitude);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Run"))
        {
            isRunning = !isRunning;
        }

        if (!isRunning)
        {
            inputMagnitude /= 1.5f;
        }

        animator.SetFloat("InputMagnitude", inputMagnitude, 0.05f, Time.deltaTime);

        if (movementDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {

            currentVelocity = movementDirection * maximumSpeed;
            characterController.SimpleMove(currentVelocity);


            Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movementDirection, Vector3.up);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);


            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", true);
        }
        else
        {

            currentVelocity *= frictionFactor;
            characterController.SimpleMove(currentVelocity);


            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", false);
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
    {
        Cursor.lockState = focus ? CursorLockMode.Locked : CursorLockMode.None;
    }
}


1. Diagonal movement will be faster than straight movement in you code. You should to use normalized direction vector when using it for speed calculations.
2. Also it's better to compare speed with float.Epsilon than with zero. Or even better to set your own constant const float EPS = 1e-4f . Because if you don't do this and the friction will be really small, the update function will process speed even if there is no visible changes.

3. You are making huge problems for yourself from the future when you are hardcoding stuff like run multiplicator value or friction factor.
4.  Movement class is breaking SRP (Single Repsonsible Principle), because it's responsable for moving character and it's animation.
